# UI loading before set value of a variable in subsribe in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, subscribe

```
 `isReqReviewSelected: boolean = false;`
```

`ngOnInit() { this.getIntProgReviewCommentsById(this.selectedAgendaId); console.log(Reviewe:'+this.isReqReviewSelected); //Always false - Ui render before value set }`

```
`getAgendasById() {
    this.agendasService.getAgendasById(this.selectedAgendaId ?? 0)
   .pipe(takeUntil(this._destroying$))
   .subscribe({
    next: (res: any) => {
      this.agenda = res;
      this.eventId = res.eventId;
      this.isReqReviewSelected = this.agenda.reqReview ?? false;
      console.log('est' + res.reqReview); // Here the value got changed
    },
    error: (err) => {
      console.log(err);
     }
      }
      );
  }`
```

<ng-template pTemplate *ngIf="isReqReviewSelected"> //Always false

I tried with return type of observable but not worked

Comment: Seems as if change detection will not be triggered. You can test this by importing `ChangeDetectorRef` and trigger it yourself with `detectChanges();`.

Comment: If your `getAgendasById()` method is in the same class as `ngOnInit` you posted, then subscription will (most probably) return the value *after* the view is initialized and displayed, so your log in onInit will return the default value of `isReqReviewSelected` (before it might get a new value from subscription). However, if your view is not updating when `isReqReviewSelected` is not false, then maybe you should paste what you're getting as a value from subscription - the `reqReview` property of res.